# Average total in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table as shown below:

Customer_Order table

```
Cust_ID    Order_id
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           4
2           5
3           6
4           7
4           8
4           9
4          10
4          11
```

How do I get average of Orders placed by customer in Oracle query.
Thanks

Comment: average of what, order_id?  That looks like a meaningless result.  Please be more specific with expected output.

Comment: Average count of Orders placed by customer

Comment: So - is there an `Orders` table?

Comment: Yes. I have Customers Table and Orders Table.

Comment: Orders(Order_ID,qty,O_name) Cusomter(Cust_id,Cust_nm)

Comment: there is no relationship between the two tables.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - the table he provided in the original post is the many-many relationship.

Comment: With "Average count of Orders placed by customer" you mean average of order quantity for each customer? Or just a count of orders for customer?

Comment: *Average count of Orders placed by **a** customer* doesn't make sense on its own. It's either *Average count of Orders per customer* (meaning number of all orders / number of all customers) or *Average count of Orders placed by customer **over some other characteristic (e.g. period month/year etc)***

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has an average function

Something like this ought to work.

```
   SELECT AVG(CUST_ID), AVG(ORDER_ID)
   FROM SOME_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(qty), Cust_ID FROM 
(Orders o JOIN Customer_Order c ON o.Order_id = c.Order_id)
GROUP BY Cust_ID
```

See it in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a9d7/2).

**Sample results**:

```
AVG(QTY)    CUST_ID
10             1
2.5            2
6              3
```

If you're looking for quantity, price, or whatever, just configure it for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id) orders_per_customer
  FROM orders
```

Output:

```
| ORDERS_PER_CUSTOMER |
|---------------------|
|                2.75 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4955b/1)** demo